# How to build c bindings for zookeeper in windows?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

facing errors in opening the solution file ..error unable to convert the solution file vs 2011 Conversion Report - Cli.vcproj: 
Converting project file 'D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.8\src\c\Cli.vcproj'. 
Done converting to new project file 'D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.8\src\c\Cli.vcxproj'. 
VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings.

Conversion Report - : 
The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.8\src\c\zookeeper.vcproj Line: 1 Column: 1 Error Message: Incorrect document syntax. The file 'D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.8\src\c\zookeeper.vcproj' has failed to load.

Comment: got the solution . open the solution file in a text editor remove first few chars which seems to be the BOM and save the file . After that you can open it in the solution explorer